# I want to restart a powershell script to load the newest version of the script as an when the script has been updated

Tags: powershell, updates, restart

I have a .ps1 running continually from start up. I want this script refreshed automatically when the script has been updated and then continue running the new script.
Maybe a restart current script at the end of the loop that it runs every 5 minutes would do it.
Currently I'm manyally stopping and restarting the script on up to 250 machines.

Comment: Have the script run via a scheduled task that reruns it every .. minutes

Comment: Question is interesting, but too broad. What exactly are you having problems with? How to transfer the current state of the script to the updated version? How to jump to a specific location within the script?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly have a loop in your script.  If the guts of the loop are the only part that is changing, then gut your loop and place its content in another script that your loop is calling.

In the following experiment, modifying Worker.ps1's Write-Host statements resulted in changes to the output each time the loop was ran.

Caller.ps1

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 200; $i++) {
    Write-Host "About to call"
    .("$PSScriptRoot\Worker.ps1")
    Write-Host "After calling"        
}
```

Worker.ps1

```
Write-Host "Working!"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Host "Done working!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Chris,
Rather than loading a script on every machine, why not place it on a share which is accessible to all machines and have them run it from that one place?

Comment: Our company removed our shares and replaced them with sharepoint. Which is another problem as it doesn't work great for us.